# How to transfer multiple material to object?

Tags: materials

I have a model assigned different materials on different part, now I import a new identical model,how can I transfer assigned materials to new object without going into edit and assign them again ??

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for the reply. Actually I'm dealing with ABC files with different anim. They are same mesh but different animation, but when I copy materials to the other, it fails :(

Comment: Hey :). Please ask that as a new question with screenshots, and description of the problem (perhaps there's an error message?).

Comment: Thank you I've just post it :)